# Как правильно прочитать данный код var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

Tags: javascript

Не могу связать воедино разрозненные (возможно поверхностные знания), помогите пожалуйста!

```js
function func() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // ((1))
  args.forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
    return arr[i] = el.toUpperCase()
  })
  document.write(args) // [A,B,C]
};
func("a", "b", "c");
```

Собственно интересует эта самая строчка `((1))`. Не могу связать то, что знаю, и понять как это действительно устроенно!

Ситуация данной функции мне абсолютно понятна, т.к. сам по себе `arguments` не является как таковым массивом, его можно сделать таковым, для этого и выполняется операция присваивания `((1))`

Я понимаю, что:

1. `Array.prototype` - прототип массивов высшего уровня
2. `slice()` метод для копирования элементов массива, принимает 2 аргумента (1 начальный индекс копирования 2 конечный)
3. `call` метод явного указания контекста вызова, Т.Е., если я правильно понял, мы указываем, что `this` при вызове `Array.prototype` будет указывать именно на "псевдомассив" `arguments`.

Единственное, что я понимаю, это то, что `args` станет новым хранилищем для аргументов в данной функции, и к нему можно будет применять все стандартные методы `Array.prototype`, а как на самом деле выполняется это присваивание, зачем там `slice`, и какая функция у `call`в этом коде, мне не понятно!

Подобный вопрос я искал на *stackoverflow*, но не нашёл! Просьба к тем, у кого есть время, объяснить подробно на доступном языке!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work

Comment: Перенес суть своих комментов в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала я приведу порядок выполнения всего выражения пошагово, а затем каждый шаг постараюсь объяснить (насчет доступности не обещаю). Итак:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

**Упрощенный порядок выполнения:**

1. Получение *объекта метода* `Array.prototype.slice`
2. Вызов метода `slice.call`, с передачей ему объекта `arguments` в качестве аргумента
3. Присвоение результата выполнения `slice` переменной `args`.

**Пояснения:**

1. Метод - это *функция*, а функции в JS являются *объектами* (экземплярами объектного типа `Function`).
   Это означает что у всех функций есть общие методы из их прототипа (и `call` - один из таких методов, он является `Function.prototype.call`)
2. Метод `call` разово выполняет "свой" экземпляр функции (от имени которой вызван) *в контексте объекта*, переданного аргументом.
   В данном случае, `slice` вызывается им в контексте объекта `arguments` - так, будто этот объект является массивом. Можно сказать что `call` временно "привязал" `slice` к объекту `arguments`, только на один вызов.
3. Результатом выполнения `slice()` является *новый массив* (новый экземпляр объектного типа `Array`), содержащий срез элементов того массива, от имени которого был вызван данный метод. При вызове этого метода без аргументов, срез содержит все элементы.
   Возвращаемым из `slice` значением, является *ссылка* на этот новый массив - так как объекты всегда передаются по ссылке (и через аргументы, и в роли операндов, и при присваивании).

Таким образом, **общий результат выполнения этого выражения:** в переменнной `args` окажется ссылка на новый массив всех элементов объекта `arguments`.

Зачем это все, почему просто не вызвать `arguments.slice()`? Потому что `arguments` не является массивом - и у него просто нет методов из прототипа `Array`.
Фактически, это выражение с `call` делает то самое, что новичками ожидается от выражения `arguments.slice()`.

---

**p.s.:**
С выходом ES6, у нас появился спред-оператор, которым можно упростить всю строку до

```
var args = [...arguments];
```

, и статический метод `Array.from`, который тоже весьма приятно выглядит:

```
var args = Array.from(arguments);
```

Comment: yar85, спасибо за ответ, разберусь как вернусь завтро с работы!

Comment: yar85, меня по прежнему не покидает ощущение "недосказанности"! Если я правильно понял, из того что знаю, и того, что вы написали: в данном коде из Array.prototype вызывается метод slice, который копирует все свойства и методы данного массива ("отца" всех массивов), метод slice возвращает новый массив , и из этого массива вызвается call() для того, чтобы this при вызове различных методов нового массива вроде forEach() reduce() и т.д. указывало на "псевдомассив" arguments? Просто вы не очень то расписали значение call(arguments)